# Raid-Controller Solution on ML350p G8

Tags: hardware-raid

Next Week, I will get an ML350 G8. So far so good. (And also two MSA 60)
But now I'm irritated, by all the things I read, about the raid situation.

With my actuall homeserver, an ML370 G6, has an P410i, which I upgraded yesterday, just for checking out (an eventually raise the selling price) to 1GB Cache an also expanded with the Expander Card (468406-B21), so far so good, now it handles 16 drives (instead of eight) and two internal LTO's as also an external one. This expander is a really nice thing.

But now I'm irritated, because I looked around for an expander for the P420i, but didn't see anything in this direction. But even when there would be an expander card for the P420i, it wouldn't help me with handling the MSA60.

So I looked around, and saw the P812, with a 100$ price tag for a refurbished one it's an option, at least from the finacial aspect. But there I would still have the problem, that I don't have enough internal SAS ports, so I checked if the 24bay expander (I allready bought one - I mean 15$ more to the P812 would still be ok) is compatible to the P812, but didn't found anything. Does someone know, if it is?
And also if the P812 at all will work on the ML350p G8.

Thank you in before for any help.
Greetings AN602

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing? It is not very clear.

Comment: Hi ewwhite, I didn't saw this before. 
It will take a while, but I look that I can explain .

Answer (score 1):

Sure. This will all work, but the internal cabling will be a mess.

Why do you need everything to flow through one RAID controller? The onboard P420i is more that sufficient for internal use.

Either way, you can use the SAS expander with the P812 controller without any issues.

Comment: Thank you. - Because I'm in need of use many things, all togehter needing around 6 internal SAS Ports (2 LTO's plus 16 SFF's) and at least 2 external. I also want to have a raid 6 on those 16 drives, instead of having two raids with 8 drives. Because thsi way, I would loss the capacity of two drives. When I would say, that I use the P420i, I still would need an 4 Port Controller and an Controller for external. And also, the solution has to be cheap.